# Not being able to load an image in python

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter

I am trying to load an image into a canvas in python. However I am getting the error: TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "C:\testimage\spongesea.jpg"

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import time
import inspect
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class game_one:

    def __init__(self):

        global root 
        global canvas_one
        root = Tk() 
        root.title("   Thanks Josh Dark
        canvas_one = Tkinter.Canvas(root, bg="BLACK")
        canvas_one.pack(expand= YES, fill= BOTH)
        canvas_one.focus_set() #allows keyboard events
        p = PhotoImage(file="C:\testimage\spongesea.jpg")
        canvas_one.create_image(0, 0, image = p, anchor=NW)
        root.grab_set()#I forget what this does.  Don't change it.
        root.lift()#This makes root appear in front of the other applications

ObjectExample = game_one()# starts the animation
```

I can open the image manually from the file, so it is not corrupted, and it is calling the correct place. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: in many languages \  has special meaning in string - ie. `\t` means `tab` - and you have `\t` in path. So use \\ (`"C:\\...\\..."`) or `/` (`"C:/.../..."`) or raw string with prefix `r` - `r"C:\...\..."`

Answer (score 1):

`PhotoImage` works only with `GIF` and `PGM/PPM`.

You have to use `Image`, `ImageTk` to work with other formats

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open("lenna.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

---

BTW: read [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) and see "Garbage Collection problem" in note.